# Future is not executed in Flutter side while called through FlutterMethodChannel from iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, future, flutter-method-channel, flutter-engine

I'm calling a Flutter method from the native side, I have no problem with Android but iOS is not working. The `Future` is not executed and the result is never returned to iOS.

Here is a simple example.

**Dart/Flutter side:**

```
MethodChannel _methodChannel = const MethodChannel("theChannel");

void initChannel() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
    switch (call.method) {
      case "flex":
        print("Flex channel");
        return Future.value('Flex');
      case "yep":
        print("Yep channel");
        return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => 'Yep');
      default:
        throw MissingPluginException();
    }
  });
}
```

**Swift/iOS side:**

```
        let engine: FlutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "theEngine")
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "theChannel", binaryMessenger: engine.binaryMessenger)

        channel.invokeMethod("yep", arguments: nil) { result in
            if(result is FlutterError) {
                print("Error")
            } else {
                print("Success")
            }
        }
```

Now the weird thing is the "flex" call works, with a `Future` completing directly.

In the "yep" case, I got the `"Yep channel"` and then the code hang there, not completing and not coming back to the iOS callback.

Everything works fine if I do the same with Android.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I seem to be running into the same issue but only iOS 16.

Comment: Hey @kevmo314! I did find a solution for this one, see the answer, it was an engine/channel problem in my case, what happens with yours?

Comment: Hmm curious, I am correctly creating the method channel on the right engine and calling `engine.run()` as well but the method channels don't seem to pick up messages correctly still. Good to hear it works though, I'll keep digging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of debugging/testing, it's working.

Here is what I noticed and will guide you to do this:

- You can fire different `FlutterEngine` but each of them will be executed in a different isolate.
- So be careful of which one you're using when creating your channel.
- You need to `FlutterEngine.run()` the engine before using it, and the next run won't do anything (if you need to run withEntrypoint afterward it directly returns without executing).

Now I got another problem with Flutter plugins not being initialized but it's another story.